# Android. How to know when upstream GCM message fails, and why

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I use this method to send upstream gcm messages in my Android app.

```
public void sendXMPPMessage(final int action, final DtoAble payload, final String messageId, final int retries) {
    ThreadPool.run(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            boolean success;
            int retry = 0;
            do {
                try {
                    XMPPClientMessage message = new XMPPClientMessage(action, getXMPPAuthentication(),
                            payload.toDto());
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString(GCM.XMPP_FIELD_DATA, Json.toJson(message));
                    mGcm.send(GCM.USER_AT_SERVER, messageId, bundle);
                    mGcm.close();
                    success = true;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                    success = false;
                }
            } while (!success && ++retry <= retries);
            if (!success) {
                broadcastNack(messageId);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I have two devices, one running on Lollipop and the other on ICS. It works fine on the lollipop devices, and sometimes on the ICS. Problem is, when it fails on the ICS, I have no chance to know that it has failed nor why. There are no exceptions thrown and the server is not receiving anything. What am I doing wrong?

Everytime I send something, I get this log output:

GcmService start Intent { act=com.google.android.gcm.intent.SEND flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.gcm.GcmService (has extras) } com.google.android.gcm.intent.SEND

and I keep getting log outputs like:

08-14 16:57:52.596    517-30365/? I/GCM﹕ GCM message com.myapp.android 0:1439560671790038%23407868f9fd7ecd

08-14 16:58:02.756    517-30365/? I/GCM﹕ GCM message com.myapp.android 0:1439560681812929%23407868f9fd7ecd

08-14 16:58:12.556    517-30365/? I/GCM﹕ GCM message com.myapp.android 0:1439560691789966%23407868f9fd7ecd

08-14 16:58:22.996    517-30365/? I/GCM﹕ GCM message com.myapp.android 0:1439560701783336%23407868f9fd7ecd

Comment: Can you add more details on how it "fails"? Do you see the packets being sent out on the link?

Comment: Is there anything in the device logcat under the "GCM" tag?

Comment: @StephenG: My server does not receive it while it otherwise does.

Comment: @morepork I've updated the question to include log details.

Comment: That log message if for a message coming from the server to your device. Did you get a registration token first on both devices?

Comment: Yes, what annoys me is that the upstream messages sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. And when it doesn't work, I don't get a nack or any other exception.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the function `onSendError(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)`

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmListenerService.html#onSendError(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: Thanks, but that method does not get called either. My GCMListenerService works though.